# MySql duplicate SUM, one to many relation ship

Tags: mysql, sum

I have following 3 tables where B, C have many to one relation ship with A, and i need to generate the following Result table with MySql

```
   Table A           Table B              Table C
    id  name       id   A.id    qty        id   A.id
    1   a          1    1       5          1    1
    2   b          2    1       10         2    1
    3   c          3    2       4          3    2
                   4    3       6          4    2
                   5    2       7



 Expected Result Table

C.id    A.id    sum(B.qty Group by A.id)
1       1       15
2       1       15
3       2       11
4       2       11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.id, a.id, sum(b.qty)
from c
inner join a on c.a_id = a.id
inner join b on b.a_id = a.id
group by c.id, a.id
```

or  in your case, you just don't need table a

```
select c.id as cid, c.a_id as aid , sum(b.qty) as totalqty
from c
inner join b on b.a_id =c.a_id
group by c.id, c.a_id;
```